# Titanium JS: How to stop a generated list view from appearing underneath the keyboard

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a window in my Titanium Alloy app which has a search bar. After submit the server returns a JSON feed which is then used to build a list view in the area underneath it.

The problem I have is that the list view takes up the whole space of the screen and a portion of it appears underneath the keyboard.

I could set a height on that list view, however I feel that this is not platform agnostic. The height for an iPhone 5 may differ than that of an Android device.

How can I ensure that the list view generated does not show up underneath the keyboard? Is there a clean, multi-platform way of doing this?

```
<Alloy>
    <Window layout="vertical">
        <SearchBar id="searchBar" hintText="Search all shows" showCancel="true" />
        <!-- List view added here will not 
             show underneath the search bar -->
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Please give an appropriate title.

Comment: Thank you, title changed, the previous was a cached title I forgot to amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to implement the same thing, but was not able to do so in a cross platform way.

For iOS i used a combination of Ti.App.keyboardFrameChanged with Ti.App.keyboardVisible. Set the functions to adjust the height of the listview.

For android i put a touchstart event on the first/main view of the template. When touched, hides the keyboard. iOS didn't always want to fire off this event if the listview started scrolling TOO quickly. Android worked just fine. Trying to put a touchstart event on the listview itself failed in every case.